# How to export to PDF from PowerBI report server using API

Tags: power-bi-report-server

How to generated PDF - report from PowerBI report server by passing parameters through the API instead generate manually from the portal

Comment: Did you managed to figure this out?

Comment: @AnkUser i think, the API is available for PBI cloud version. But I am expecting for PBI Report Server version.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet available and will be abailable soon as (preview) phase.

Here is the [document from Microsoft](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-report-to-pdf-pptx-and-png-files-using-power-bi-rest-api/) for the API and PDF download.